# Render fields url in tpl.php

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type (music) with fields(image,track,title). I used a soundmanager player to display my track with its tpl.php(bar.tpl.php).

I have tried to display url of the image field inside the (bar.tpl.php) but got only (http://localhost/mysite) using this code

```
<div class="sm2-inline-element album-art">
 <img src="<?php $file = file_load($node->field_image_boss['und'][0]['fid']); 
  print file_create_url($file->uri); ?>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [IMAGE URL FORMATTER](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module

Then on view's, click on your field, for formatter you can select Image URL.

[image]

**Then on your tpl.php file use** `<?php print $fields["field_image_boss"]->content; ?>`

**Note** if you see that your field gets printed with extra markup such as `<span>url</span>` instead of just `url`. Then you need to remove extra views container markups

On your view's edit page. Under Format click on the 1st settings and uncheck  Add views row classes and Add striping (odd/even), first/last row classes

Also, on the 2nd settings, uncheck Provide default field wrapper elements

Lastly, click on your field, and under **STYLES SETTINGS** make sure everything is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You can use [image_style_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) if you only want to dsplay an image. Like this:

```
<div class="sm2-inline-element album-art">
 <img src="<?php $file = file_load($node->field_image_boss['und'][0]['fid']); 
  print image_style_url('STYLE_NAME (e.g. large, or use custom)', $file->uri); ?>" />
</div>
```